# Parameterized interface in systemverilog

Tags: system-verilog

I have a full AXI interface and a lite AXI interface as shown below:

```
interface axi_full ();
  logic [63:0] wdata;
  logic .      wid;
  logic wcredit;
endinterface

interface axi_lite();
  logic [63:0] wdata;
  logic wcredit;
endinterface
```

Is there a way I can use only one interface with a parameter lite something like below instead of two separate interfaces? The only difference is there is no wid in the case of AXI lite.

```
interface axi #(bit Lite = 1'b0) ();
  ...
  ...
endinterface
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. You should be able to use the  `axi_full` and leave the `wid` signal unused.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the standard that would prevent from using generate blocks inside the interfaces. So, the following is supposed to work:

```
interface axi #(FULL=1)();
  logic [63:0] wdata;
  logic       wid;
  if (FULL != 0) begin: fff
      logic wcredit;
  end
endinterface

module top;
  axi#(1) full();
  axi#(0) lite();
  imod fm(full);
  //imod lm(lite);
endmodule

module imod(axi i);
  initial begin
    $display(i.wdata, i.wid, i.fff.wcredit);
  end
endmodule
```

The problem as always is in vendor implementation. The above seems to work nicely in the cadence's `nc`. Uncommenting the 'lite' string will cause it to generate an error.

However, synopsys vcs, at least the one in eda playground refuses to compile it complaining about unimplemented feature of xmrs into interfaces.

Synthesis might have their own thoughts about this. So, the best way is to use separate definitions.

Also it depends on how you use them, `modports` can be handy. They are implemented better and the following example should work everywhere:

```
interface axi_if;
  logic [63:0] wdata;
  logic       wid;
  logic wcredit;
  modport full (input wdata, wid, wcredit);
  modport lite(input wdata, wid);
endinterface

module top;
  axi_if intf();
  fmod fm(intf);
  lmod lm(intf);
endmodule


module fmod(axi_if.full i);
    initial begin      
      $display(i.wdata, i.wid, i.wcredit);
    end
endmodule

module lmod(axi_if.lite i);
    initial begin      
      $display(i.wdata, i.wid); //, i.wcredit);
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying is not possible, but you can place wid signal inside `ifdef compile directive like following

```
interface axi();
  logic [63:0] wdata;
`ifdef AXI_FULL
  logic       wid;
`endif
  logic wcredit;
endinterface
```

define AXI_FULL when you are not using AXI-Lite
also take this thing into consideration while connecting axi interface

Comment: This will not work if you want both AXI and AXI Lite interfaces in the same simulation.

Comment: Yes, If you want to use both interfaces then it won't make any sense.